# Problem with Saga in Qgis 2.14.6

Tags: qgis, error, saga

I am trying to run saga tool however I always received errors.

I am using Ubuntu Xenial Xerus (16.04), Qgis 2.14.6 and Saga 2.2.7.

Log (OGR) error:
2016-09-07T15:22:28 1   Data source is invalid ()

See images of errors:
[image]

```
Log (Processing) Error:
Error: input file [/tmp/processing25e6c401b76f41efb6bb44365b964fdf/4ee2c30104ca4cf39033d19cdb51167e/srtmriachosantanaSIRGAS200023S.sgrd]
            Error: DEM
            ____________________________

            #####   ##   #####    ##
            ###     ###  ##       ###
            ###   # ## ##  #### # ##
            ### ##### ##    # #####
            ##### #   ##  ##### #   ##
            ____________________________

            SAGA Version: 2.2.7

            ____________________________
            library path: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/saga/
            library name: libta_preprocessor
            library     : Preprocessing
            tool        : Fill Sinks XXL (Wang & Liu)
            author      : Copyrights (c) 2007 by Volker Wichmann
            processors  : 8 [8]
            ____________________________

            Load grid: /tmp/processing25e6c401b76f41efb6bb44365b964fdf/4ee2c30104ca4cf39033d19cdb51167e/srtmriachosantanaSIRGAS200023S.sgrd...
            failed

            Usage: saga_cmd ta_preprocessor 5 [-ELEV <str>] [-FILLED <str>] [-MINSLOPE <double>]
            -ELEV:<str>         DEM
            Grid (input)
            -FILLED:<str>       Filled DEM
            Grid (output)
            -MINSLOPE:<double>  Minimum Slope [Degree]
            Floating point
            Minimum: 0.000000
            Default: 0.100000
2016-09-07T15:22:28 2   Error loading result layer:
            Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/gui/Postprocessing.py", line 76, in handleAlgorithmResults
                out.name))
              File "/usr/share/qgis/python/plugins/processing/tools/dataobjects.py", line 199, in load
                + '\nCheck the processing framework log to look for errors')
            RuntimeError: Could not load layer: /tmp/processing25e6c401b76f41efb6bb44365b964fdf/b5e9bd717ed34b15a08ebaf91e8bee8b/FILLED.sdat
            Check the processing framework log to look for errors
```

Comment: Did you try directly with SAGA-GIS (Terrain analysis->Hydrology->flow accumulation->top down). Just to know if the issue resides in SAGA or QGIS. I did try the same with one of my tiff rasters and it worked in SAGA but not in qgis (on manjaro). Using saga might thus be a work around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saga version 2.2.7 is not supported. Please compile the 2.2.3 downloading the code from here https://sourceforge.net/projects/saga-gis/files/SAGA%20-%202.2/SAGA%202.2.3/.
Do not install from software center (there is 2.2.7 version)

Comment: It seems to be a bit more complicated. I managed to run SAGA 2.3.1 vector algs in the processing toolbox on Ubuntu 16.10 (no ubuntugis involved), and SAGA 2.2.7 from ubuntugis on Ubuntu 16.04 as well. But I don't know why it works for me and not for others.